# How to overload equality and print in java?

Tags: java, python, operator-overloading, overloading

In java, how can you overload the equality operation and print operation for a class?

Like in python, you can do it by doing `def __eq__(self):` or `def __str__(self):`, but how can this be done in java?

I know you can just manually make a method and call it like `equals` or something, but I wanted to find out if there is an actual one that works with the `==` operator and `System.out.print()` function.

Does anyone know?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot overload `==` in Java.

Comment: You can override .equals(Object) though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java does not support operator overloading. `==` will *always* test for reference equality.

[`System.out.print()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.Object%29) uses [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) to generate its output. You can override `toString` in your class.

And you are correct about overriding the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method with one caveat: If you are overriding the `equals` method, you are also supposed to override the [`hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method so that your object will behave correctly with `HashSet`s and the like. Details about the contract between `hashCode` and `equals` can be found in the documentation I linked you to.

/edit

```
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Point(1, 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that when you override `equals` you generally must also override `hashCode` for the object to behave nicely in the collections framework.

Comment: Also consider adding the `@Override` annotation (it has more benefits than you might think).

Comment: @A.R.S. Oops, thought I had my IDE setup to put that there for me. Added.

Comment: @Jessemon Seeing as primitives do not have references, that would be rather difficult. `==` tests for equality among primitives and reference equality among reference types.

Comment: @omega - See the article [How to Write an Equality Method in Java](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html). Good stuff!